# If $\oint \vec D \cdot d\vec a = 0$ everywhere then $\vec D = \vec 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, mathematical-physics

I'm reading a book on Electricity and Magnetism.  In an example using the electric displacement they write that, since $\oint \vec D \cdot d\vec a = 0$ in the example, we can infer that $\vec D = \vec 0$.  I would buy that argument if the integral were any path integral, but here I believe that $\oint$ refers to an oriented closed-path integral, yes?

If it helps, here's as much as I know about the objects involved: $\vec D = \epsilon_0\vec E + \vec P$ where $\epsilon_0$ is a physical constant, $\vec E$ is the net electric field, and $\vec P$ is the polarization, which mathematically is just any (presumably continuous, I would think) vector field.  Only $\vec E$ is guaranteed to be conservative.

So how do we know that $\vec D = \vec 0$ rather than merely every closed path integral being zero, so that in effect this only shows that $\vec D$ is conservative?  Is there some further feature of the physical system that would imply a property of $\vec D$ which allows us to make this inference?

---

To give context, in case it helps, the example comes from Griffith's *Electrodynamics* 3rd Ed.  It's problem 4.4.15 where $\vec P = \frac k r \hat r$ inside a thick spherical shell of inner radius *a* and outer radius *b*, where *k* is some arbitrary constant.

Comment: The boundary is a closed surface, not a closed contour.

Comment: Is there any free charge density in either $r>b$ or $r<a$?  Is there any specification about $\vec E$ on the boundary of the shell?

Comment: @MarkViola There is no free charge at all in the problem.  This is what justifies saying $\oint \vec D \cdot d\vec a = 0$.  There is no explicit statement about the net field, although we could try to investigate it.  But I think that might be against the spirit of the exercise since it is intended to emphasize how easy it is to work with the displacement.

Comment: You're right that just because $\int_S \mathbf{D\cdot n} \, da = 0$ for every closed surface $S$, it doesn't follow that $\mathbf{D=0}$. Because the integral vanishing for every closed surface is only equivalent to $\text{div}(\mathbf{D})=0$. To determine $\mathbf{D}$, you also need to know how the curl behaves. I suspect that the lack of free charge along with some sort of symmetry argument forces the curl of $\mathbf{D}$ to also be $0$ (or simply that $\mathbf{D}$ has to be a radial field). From this we can conclude that $\mathbf{D=0}$. But I'm not too sure of the details...

Comment: @Addem I posted a solution a couple of weeks ago.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We shall assume that we are analyzing a problem in electrostatics.

Let $\displaystyle V$ denote the open domain $\displaystyle V=\{\vec r|0<a<|\vec r|<b\}$ and $\displaystyle \partial V$ denote its boundary.  We shall denote the magnitude of the position vector by $r$.  That is, $r=|\vec r|$.

---

Suppose that the Polarization density $\displaystyle \vec P(\vec r)$ is given by

$$\vec P(\vec r)=
\begin{cases}
k\,\frac{\vec r}{r^2}&, \vec r\in \bar V\\\\ 0&,\vec r \,\,\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then the volume polarization charge density $\displaystyle \rho_P(\vec r)-\nabla \cdot \vec P(\vec r)$ is

$$  \rho_P(\vec r)=-\frac{k}{r^2}$$

and the polarization surface charge density $\sigma_P(\vec r)=\left. \hat n \cdot \vec P(\vec r)\right|_{\vec r \in \partial V}$ is

$$\sigma_P(\vec r)=\begin{cases}
\frac{k}{b}&, r=b\\\\
-\frac{k}{a}&,r=a
\end{cases}$$

---

Suppose further that the free charge density $\rho(\vec r)=0$ for $\vec r \in \mathbb{R}^3$.   Then by the spherical symmetry of the problem we see that $\vec P=\hat r P_r(r)$, $\vec E=\hat r E_r(r)$, and $\vec D=\hat r D_r(r)$. That is all vector fields are radial and depend on $r$ only.

---

Since there is no free charge density, $\nabla \cdot \vec D=0$.  From the divergence theorem we see that for all closed surfaces $S$, $\oint_{S}\vec D(\vec r)\cdot \hat n\,dS=0$.  Take $S$ to be a sphere of raidus $r$.  Then,

$$\oint_{S}\vec D(\vec r)\cdot \hat n\,dS=4\pi r^2 D_r(r)=0$$

and we conclude that $\vec D=0$.

Comment: So I guess the answer amounts to, in summary, that: Because every integral over a surface is zero, and because $\vec D$ is spherically symmetric, we can infer that the strength of $D$ must be zero everywhere.  Do I have that right?

Comment: You have it now.  Well done.

Comment: Sorry to bother but I'm wondering how far we can push this.  There's nothing that special about spherical symmetry right?  In general mathematically, if we had some reason to think that the field were uniform on every box, then the same result would hold.  So all you need is the idea that every point is on a continuous equipotential closed surface.  I think that's as far as you can push the idea here, right?